# How to define Watches in Artifactory for LDAP Users

Tags: ldap, artifactory

Artifactory allows to set Watches on specific repositories to get notification when changes happen.

When you define an internal user, this works properly.
For LDAP Users, there is no option to set a watch on a repository.

Are special settings needed to enable this feature for LDAP Users or is it imposible without any workarounds?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are describing is not related to the LDAP users but due to one of the below options:

1. You are not creating the LDAP users locally on Artifactory, meaning that you are validating the user vs the LDAP server on the fly and not creating the user on Artifactory. If this is the case then the reason for you not to be able to set a watcher is that from Artifactory perspective it doesn't have a user with details (email as an example).
2. If #1 is not the case and you do create the LDAP users (automatically or not ) in Artifactory then check if those users have email defined upon creation in Artifactory.